# Use nginx reverse proxy for redirection

Tags: nginx, proxy, redirect, reverse-proxy

I have `a.b` domain (for example) and want to serve some github pages (`username.github.io/project`) in `a.b/c`. It means that I also want to keep my browser url to `a.b/c` and showing contents of `username.github.io/project`.

I have following settings in nginx module

```
location /c {       
    proxy_pass http://username.github.io/project;
    proxy_redirect http://username.github.io http://a.b;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

if I change `proxy_set_header Host $http_host` to `proxy_set_header Host $proxy_host` or `$host`, it just redirect to `http://username.github.io/project` which is not I meant to. How can I do?

Comment: Please use example.com as an example domain.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Simply send the right Host header to your proxy target by **removing** the `proxy_set_header Host $http_host` line.

If `a.b` is configured as a server name in your server block then you don't even need `proxy_redirect` directive if you use a trailing slash in your location prefix and in your `proxy_pass` target as explained [in the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_redirect) :

> ```
> Syntax:  proxy_redirect default;
>          proxy_redirect off;
>          proxy_redirect redirect replacement;
> Default: proxy_redirect default;
> Context: http, server, location
> ```
>
> [ ...]
>
> The default replacement specified by the default parameter uses the parameters of the location and proxy_pass directives. Hence, the two configurations below are equivalent:
>
> ```
> location /one/ {
>     proxy_pass     http://upstream:port/two/;
>     proxy_redirect default;
> }
>
> location /one/ {
>     proxy_pass     http://upstream:port/two/;
>     proxy_redirect http://upstream:port/two/ /one/;
> }
> ```
>
> [ ....]

So, this should do it :

```
server {

    server_name a.b;

    location /c/ {       
        proxy_pass http://username.github.io/project/;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_buffering off;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
proxy_redirect off;
```

So your settings will be

```
location /c {

    proxy_pass http://username.github.io/project;
    proxy_redirect http://username.github.io;
    proxy_set_header Host username.github.io;
    proxy_set_header X-Host username.github.io;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_buffering off;
}
```

Comment: In your answer, you added the `X-Host` directive, not `proxy_redirect off`. Is that what you meant to do?